# Sum Of A Finite Series To Some Power

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we have a finite series $a_1, a_2, ... a_n$, which has all positive terms, and whose sum is one.
I was wondering about bounds for the sum of $a_i^2$, and I realized the maximum would be 1, and the minimum would be $\frac{1}{n}$.

What would happen for a general power k? (i.e., what are the bounds for the sum of $a_i^k$ for any k?)

Comment: multinomial theorem may help is my first guess.

Comment: Are the coefficients reals or positive reals? how did you prove the bound for the case k=2?

Comment: For a lower bound, we can use Holder's Inequality

Comment: @SC30 I forgot the positive, thanks. And I wrote: $\sum a_i^2 = \sum (\frac{1}{n}-b_i)^2 = \sum (\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{2b_i}{n}+b_i^2) = \frac{1}{n}-\frac{2}{n}\sum b_i+\sum b_i^2$ and notice that $\sum b_i=0$

Comment: @AlanYan How would you use Holder here?

Comment: The answer that was posted is basically a case of the holder inequality. A more specified inequality would be the Power Mean Inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arithmetic mean-quadratic mean inequality says that $$\frac1n = \frac{a_1+\cdots + a_n}{n}\leq \sqrt{\frac{a_1^2 + \cdots + a_n^2}{n}}$$which implies $a_1^2 + \cdots + a_n^2\geq \frac1n$. The above inequality generalises to any power $k>1$, giving
$$
\frac{1}{n} = \frac{a_1+\cdots + a_n}{n}\leq \sqrt[k]{\frac{a_1^k+\cdots + a_n^k}{n}}
$$
which implies that $a_1^k+\cdots + a_n^k\geq \frac1{n^{k-1}}$. The maximum of $1$ is always the same, since all the numbers become smaller as we raise them to the $k$'th power, so the sum cannot increase (and it stays the same if one number is $1$ and all the others are $0$).

Comment: This is true for $k>1$ (And this is a strict bound). What happens for $k<1$?

Comment: @Omry For $k< 1, k\neq 0$, the general inequality as stated above changes direction, as does $a_i^k<a_i$. So instead we get $1\leq a_1^k +\cdots + a_n^k\leq \frac{1}{n^{k-1}}$.